# Must declare a scalar variable in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get the error?

> Must declare a scalar variable @wight

In my stored procedure?

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].Vector
    (@word Varchar, @Wight double ) 
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
    DocId, TermWight * @Wight as "ss", word, id,
    wordid, IDF, TFij     
FROM            TermWeight

WHERE  (word = @word) and (TermWight <> 0)
```

Comment: Because you're using a variable that hasn't been declared.

Comment: There is no `double` datatype. When you fix that you will get `Must declare the scalar variable "@word".`

Comment: the problem in @wight variable

Comment: Seeing as how you've changed your first parameter from `@DocId int` to `@word Varchar` (without specifying a length, I might add), can you please post your *exact* query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Vector
(@word VARCHAR (100) , @Wight float)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
    DocId ,
    TermWight * @Wight AS 'ss' ,
    word ,
    id ,
    wordid ,
    IDF ,
    TFij
FROM TermWeight

WHERE (word = @word)
AND (TermWight <> 0)
```

Couple of issues previously. Varchar should have a length applied (100) in my example. As mentioned by someone else Double is not a sql type float is the nearest equivalent (I believe)

Answer (score 2):

You are using @word but it is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Why would that is explain the message "Must declare a scalar variable *@wight*"

Comment: No fair, he edited the question after I posted my answer!